# Sonarqube exclude files that doesn't match a rule on code coverage

Tags: sonarqube

I have several packages inside my project, inside each I have something like:

```
- MyClass.java
- MyClassDAO.java
- MyClassResource.java
```

I want to exclude only MyClass from sonar code coverage, is it possible?

Comment: I assume this pattern repeats from package to package(?). Does `MyClass.java` follow a naming convention?

Comment: Yes, It's the same pattern on every package. No naming convention apart from the fact that `MyClass` will have the same name of it's package. So, inside package `foo` I'll have `foo.java` `fooDAO.java` and `fooResource.java`

Comment: Also, it extends `BaseEntity`, not sure if it helps

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam can I use full regex on the exclude field?

Comment: It's not that sophisticated @FrankTominc. You have `*`, `**`, and `?`.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Is there a workaround for what I need?

Comment: Assuming you don't want to ignore these classes for issue purposes, not an easy one @FrankTominc. You can write a coverage exclusion for each individual file, institute a naming convention and write one pattern, or just live with the hit to the coverage.